# OFS when using if-else statement in awk

Tags: unix, awk

I have a simple text file, delimited by multiple spaces, and with a different number of columns (6 or 5).

What I am trying to do is, for the rows with more than 5 columns, combine the 2 last columns in one, doing:

`cat data.txt | awk '{if(NF>5) print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5"_"$6; else print $0} OFS="," ' > data.csv`

The problem is that the `OFS` is not working for the else statement.

Example - input:

```
a   d   e  t er ap
b   q   j  n mm
```

Output that I am getting:

```
a,d,e,t,er_ap
b   q   j  n mm
```

Desirable output:

```
a,d,e,t,er_ap
b,q,j,n,mm
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any sane reason for setting OFS in an actionless condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your OFS in the `BEGIN` block so that it's a comma before any processing happens. Also when you do `print $0` without manipulating the line in any way, awk will just spit out the line as-is with whatever delimiters are in place in the source file. Personally I think that's dumb, but that's awk. As a workaround, just set one column equal to itself, then print:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{if(NF>5) print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5"_"$6; else {$1=$1;print $0}}' data.txt
```

If you anticipate more than 6 columns you can just have it toss underscores for all of them after column 5 with some `printf` trickery too

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf (i==NF)?"%s\n":(i>=5)?"%s_":"%s,", $i}}' data.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked just fine. I always have problems to remember this ```$1=$1```.    Anyway, thanks again!